# For Mann Whitney U (Wilcoxon Ranked Sum), what is the difference between tests that follow the formula and use the smallest value?

Tags: wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

I've learned two types of Mann Whitney U test, one use's a formula to calculate U, and another just takes the smallest total of the ranks and compares this with the critical value grid. What's the difference between these two ways of doing Mann Whitney U, and why doesn't everyone just pick the smallest total rank and compare that with the critical value table?

For context, I come from a psychology background where the test appears to be done without using the formula primarily.

Thanks

Comment: See 
[this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mann%E2%80%93Whitney_U_test#Illustration_of_calculation_methods) for a discussion of (a) the equivalence of Mann-Whitney U and Wilcoxon rank sum tests, with an example, (b) history of the tests, and (c) comments on computer implementations.

Comment: There are a number of posts on site that discuss variant definitions of this statistic and their relationships (and the fact that the tests are equivalent, yielding identical p-values)